# gssapi/kerberos/active directory/ubuntu - Wrong principal in request

Tags: kerberos, single-sign-on, gssapi, spnego

I'm trying to setup a Clientserver with a Webservice to which Users of an Active Directory should be able to login with SSO.

I'm using SPNEGO with Kerberos on a Ubuntu 14.04 Server and nginx proxy to Naviserver for the Webservice to do that and get the Error Code: majorStatus: 851968 , minorStatus: 2529639056 (Wrong principal in request)

/etc/krb5.conf

```
    [libdefaults]
        default_realm = TEST.LOCAL
        default_keytab_name = /etc/staging.keytab
        rdns = false
        ignore_acceptor_hostname = true
        dns_lookup_realm = false
        dns_lookup_kdc = false
        default_tkt_enctypes = des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc arcfour-hmac-md5 rc4-hmac
        default_tgs_enctypes = des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc arcfour-hmac-md5 rc4-hmac
        permitted_enctypes = des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc arcfour-hmac-md5 rc4-hmac
        allow_weak_crypto = true
        kdc_timesync = 1
        clockskew = 100
        ccache_type = 4
        forwardable = true
        proxiable = true
        ticket_lifetime = 25h
        renew_lifetime = 7d
        kdc_req_checksum_type = 4
[realms]
        TEST.LOCAL = {
                kdc = something.test.local
                admin_server = something.test.local
                default_domain = TEST.LOCAL
        }
[domain_realm]
        live.test.smth = TEST.LOCAL
        .live.test.smth = TEST.LOCAL
        staging.smth.else = TEST.LOCAL
        .staging.smth.else = TEST.LOCAL
```

in /etc/hosts is no 127.0.0.1

```
ActiveDirIP    test.local
myIP    staging.smth.else
```

I have a keytab File generated from the Active Directory Admins with

```
ktpass /princ HTTP/staging.smth.else@TEST.LOCAL /mapuser user-staging@test.local /pass *** /out staging.keytab /crypto DES-CBC-CRC /kvno 0 /ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL
```

And it works when I call kinit:

```
~$ kinit -S http/staging.smth.else@TEST.LOCAL staging@TEST.LOCAL
~$ klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1002
Default principal: staging@TEST.LOCAL

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
2016-02-12 13:31:44  2016-02-12 23:31:44  http/staging.smth.else@TEST.LOCAL
    renew until 2016-02-13 13:31:41

~$ kinit http/staging.smth.else@TEST.LOCAL
~$ klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1002
Default principal: http/staging.smth.else@TEST.LOCAL

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
2016-02-12 13:30:58  2016-02-12 23:30:58  krbtgt/TEST.LOCAL@TEST.LOCAL
    renew until 2016-02-13 13:30:49

~$ kinit staging@TEST.LOCAL
~$ klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1002
Default principal: staging@TEST.LOCAL

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
2016-02-12 13:32:13  2016-02-12 23:32:13  krbtgt/TEST.LOCAL@TEST.LOCAL
    renew until 2016-02-13 13:32:09
```

kvno is 3 but the Admin told me that kvno in Windows is irrelevant.

```
kvno staging@TEST.LOCAL
staging@TEST.LOCAL kvno = 3
```

In NaviServer Config is defined:

```
ns_section ns/server/${server}/module/knspnego
ns_param Krb5KeyTabFile "/etc/staging.keytab"
ns_param Krb5ServiceName "HTTP@staging.smth.else"
ns_param AuthType "SPNEGO"
```

hostname

```
hostname -f
staging.smth.else
```

Do you have any ideas where the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. 
In the keytab files was the wrong /crypto for our setting. It's working with /crypto ALL

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
Replaced the encryption type `rc4-hmac` with these:

```
arcfour-hmac
aes128-cts
aes256-cts
des-cbc-crc
des-cbc-md5
```

Then restarted my services, that fixed it